# Inconsistent auto-hyperlink behavior between post preview and actual post

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

In the preview zone for posting, this link:

> [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allégorie_de_la_caverne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/All%C3%A9gorie_de_la_caverne)

breaks just before the `é`. Here's a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image: screenshot of the link in the preview zone]

However, as you can see in the actual post, the link breaks at the slash after /wiki.

Comment: *Obligatory comment that the fix would be to use proper markdown.*